# Compilation of contract with include

Tags: smartcontracts, aeternity-blockchain

I’m currently struggling to compile a contract (on aeternity's Sophia language) with include of a custom library “Library.aes” which resides in a separate file at the same level of the filesystem as the using contract.

The library looks like

```
namespace Library =
  type number = int
  function inc(x : number) : number = x + 1
```

The contract is using it like this

```
include "Library.aes"
```

When I compile (locally using compiler node) the contract, I always get

```
"Couldn't find include file 'Library.aes'\n"
```

also tried to pass the full path to the include, same result.

Is there a need to define the attribute options.file_system somehow?

Answer (score 2):

let’s use the same example:

```
~/Quviq/Aeternity/aesophia_http [git:master]: FOO="include \\\"Bar.aes\\\"\\n\\ncontract Foo =\\n  entrypoint foo() = Bar.bar()"
~/Quviq/Aeternity/aesophia_http [git:master]: BAR="namespace Bar =\\n  function bar() = 42"
~/Quviq/Aeternity/aesophia_http [git:master]: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"code\":\"$FOO\",\"options\":{\"backend\":\"fate\",\"file_system\":{\"Bar.aes\":\"$BAR\"}}}" -X POST http://localhost:3080/compile
{"bytecode":"cb_+IJGA6AANCB3UsSiP2HGHRML0dG95vNT9JsqZQMjPYAfEG1w6cC4Va3+RNZEHwA3ADcAGg6CPwEDP/5sbA2iAjcABwEDVP64/p9/ADcABwQDEWxsDaKjLwMRRNZEHxFpbml0EWxsDaIhLkJhci5iYXIRuP6ffw1mb2+CLwCFNC4yLjAAfreb3w=="}
```

Beware the quoting of strings, but apart from that it is rather straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

This post is pretty old but thought on responding anyway.

Did you tried this by using aeproject?

https://github.com/aeternity/aepp-aeproject-js

Try to put your contract code under the file structure and use the deploy script so you can work it out locally first and the deploy to testnet or mainnet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Erlang installed you may use [aesophia_cli](https://github.com/aeternity/aesophia_cli) instead of hosting a local node. Then it should search for include files in the same directory as your main `.aes` file.